# Why does using *kwargs.values() within a lambda function's parameter list result in a SyntaxError?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

```py
(lambda **kwargs: *kwargs.values())(a=1, b=2)
```

This code snippet raises a SyntaxError, specifically stating "invalid syntax" pointing to the use of the * operator within the parameter list of the lambda function. However, I've noticed that using the * operator to unpack values from kwargs works perfectly fine within the function body, as demonstrated in the following lambda expression:

```py
python (lambda *args, **kwargs: max(*args, *kwargs.values()))(1, 2, 3, a=4, b=5)
```

In this case, kwargs.values() is unpacked using * within the function body without any issues.

I'm curious about why this behavior occurs. Why does using *kwargs.values() within the parameter list of a lambda function result in a SyntaxError, while using it within the function body works without any problems?

Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't specifically related to the usage of `kwargs` and `lambda`, and just boils down to how unpacking works (as in we don't even need a dictionary to reproduce this behavior).

In the **second** example `*kwargs.values()` expands `kwargs.values()` to individual arguments which are then being passed to `max`, conceptually equivalent to

```py
li = [1, 2]
max(li[0], li[1])
```

In the **first** example, unpacking just makes no sense and is equivalent to

```py
li = [1, 2]
*li
SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here
```

Comment: d = [1] def unpack_here(arg1): print(arg1) unpack_here(*d) *d,

I understand your argument that pure unpacking does not make sense, but you can put any literal or variable like li without * and it will be omitted without error. I see the point that you cannot have more than one variable without any DS holding it like a tuple (*d,) and no operator between, etc.   

When you unpack to the function, there is no syntax error. Is it because arguments are passed as a tuple?